# Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, windows, opencv, cmake, pip

I am trying to install opencv-python on windows but after running the `pip install opencv-python` command I keep geting the following error: `ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`.

I'm using python version 3.9.0 and pip version pip 20.2.4.

I've tried upgrading both my pip version as well as running `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`, as found on similar threads, but none of these seems to solve the issue.

The full console output after running the command:

```
    Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 88.9 MB 3.3 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.17.3
  Downloading numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.3 MB 6.4 MB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python, numpy
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl1finc77'
       cwd: C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gfwb0hqn\opencv-python
  Complete output (153 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gfwb0hqn/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.9 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for numpy: filename=numpy-1.19.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=4816060 sha256=18bd09a9c5e107a2e44f8466057d0b423a244fb84949a6d5a6d88534a58e1e4a
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-v6mmdzxn\wheels\a3\17\dd\f2dba23a35bb6008732772ccfb13d3d0e537fbc6919ce6862b
Successfully built numpy
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well "could not find any instance of Visual Studio" seems quite clear. Install the Visual Studio compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no pre-built Python 3.9 binary wheels yet for `opencv-python`. To compile from source, you must install build tools (Visual Studio 15 2017) as indicated by the error:

```
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.9 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
```

`opencv-python` Python 3.9 wheel tracking issue: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/382

Comment: You're right, I've already installed VS 2017 thinking this might be the problem but without the proper build tools. After reinstalling with those I've managed to get pip install working as well, thank you.

Comment: Make sure to check "Workloads > Python Environment" when installing Visual Studio.